# GwtAudio RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method initialData in org.vaadin.gwtav.client.GwtAudioServerRpc

Tags: html5-audio, vaadin8, wildfly-13

I 'm using this library to implement an audio playback in vaadin 8:
https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audiovideo

This is the code of my view. Only a layout and a GwatAudio instance:

```
     public void init() {
                layout = new VerticalLayout();
                String filename = "Ensoniq-3.wav";
                String pathName = "C:\\PERSEO\\TADPLAYER\\";
                
                ConnectorAudio con = new ConnectorAudio(filename, pathName);            
                GwtAudio atc = new GwtAudio(con);
                layout.addComponent(atc);
            }
```

And this is the resource subclass that I need to create a Gwtaudio

```
     public class ConnectorAudio implements ConnectorResource  {
            
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8806461248248864379L;
            private String fileName;
            private StreamResource resource;
            
            
            public ConnectorAudio(String fileName, String pathName) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.fileName = fileName;
                StreamSource stream = new StreamSource() {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream getStream() {
                        try {
                            return new FileInputStream(pathName + fileName);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                        }
                    };
                    this.resource = new StreamResource(stream, this.fileName );
            }
            
        
            @Override
            public String getMIMEType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return this.resource.getMIMEType();
            }
        
            @Override
            public DownloadStream getStream() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  return resource.getStream();
            }
        
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return this.resource.getFilename();
            }
        
            public Resource getResource() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return this.resource;
            }
        
        }
```

The audio is even working, but not properly, and when the view is loaded, always this exception is triggered:
I think there must be a problem related to wildFly 13 , because of the exception that is triggered [image]when I try to create an instance of gwt audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to seek and streaming to work correctly, component needs to know the length of the file. In Vaadin 8, plain `ConnectorResource` does not give that information.

You have two alternatives. The `FileResource` has that capability, and if it fits your case (which I think so, as your example have file path), you should use that.

```
    File file = new File("C:\\PERSEO\\TADPLAYER\\Ensoniq-3.wav");
    FileResouce fileResource = new FileResource(file);
    audio.setSource(fileResource);
```

By code inspection your `ConnectorAudio` is attempt of recreating `FileResource` that already exists, but you miss this one feature of setting the content length.

For other scenarios, the add-on comes with  `ContentLengthConnectorResource` wrapper, so that it is possible to use e.g. `ClassResource`, if you know by other means the content-length.

```
    ClassResource audioResource = new ClassResource("/test.mp3");
    long length = 725240;
    audio.setSource(new ContentLengthConnectorResource(audioResource,length));
```